# Authentication of API using using Amazon API Gateway

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, aws-api-gateway

I am new with AWS and currently, I have a project running on Laravel 5.2 and the API which I have do not have any kind of authentication like the JWT for example. I was looking for API authentication and thought of using Amazon API Gateway. I wanted to know will Amazon API Gateway will help me with API authentication like a token-based authentication for each API. And should I go for the service or should I stick to the JWT solution?

Please share some knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement JWT token validation at AWS API Gateway level keeping uour API logic clean.

To do this, you can use a special AWS Lambda function called [custom authorizer](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/README.md) where you can read the token from HTTP headers and validate it. This way your internal API is accessible only for the requests coming with a valid JWT Token.